# JSX todo list delete without using props or state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I am struggling using function to delete item on array when clicking the delete button. I want to make it without using props or state.

Can anyone show me what am I doing wrong?

It shows on the page but does not do anything and errors on console.

```
function Todolist() {
   const [todo, setTodo] = useState({desc:'', date:''});
   const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
   

   const inputChanged = (e) => {
       setTodo({...todo, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
   }
   const addTodo = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, todo]);
}
 const handleRemove = () => {
    todos.filter((todo, i) => i !== index)
}
    return(
     <div>
         <label> Description:
            <input name="desc" value={todo.desc} onChange={inputChanged}></input>
         </label>
         <label> Date:
            <input type="date" name="date" value={todo.date} onChange={inputChanged}></input>
         </label>
         <button onClick={addTodo}>Add</button>
        <table>
            <tbody> 
               <tr><th >Date</th><th>Description</th></tr>
                {
                   todos.map((todo, index )=> 
                   <tr key={index}>
                       <td>{todo.date}</td>
                       <td>{todo.desc}</td>
                       <td><button onClick={handleRemove}>Delete</button></td>
                       </tr>
                       )
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
    );
}

export default Todolist ;
```

Comment: This approach is going to fail at some point.  You should be tracking your todos by a uid, not the index in the array.

https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: Is there any reason you do not want to use props nor state? This goes against the core React principle. React triggers a re-render if either the props or the state (using the state setter) changes. You can manage a list of todo items without both of those, but then the view won't re-render. This results in the user not being able to see any changes.

Comment: Oh  I was not familiar with the props and state just yet... Sorry. I will learn soon and try to fix them!! Thank you for ur information tho!!

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is you are simply filtering the array but not assigning the result of that to anywhere.

Reading from the [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) documentation:

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Based on that, you need to assign the return value of `.filter()` with `setToDos` as:

```
setTodos(prevToDos =>
   prevToDos.filter((todo, i) => i !== index)
)
```

And probably you need to pass to `handleRemove` the `index` what you are using in `.filter()`:

```
<button onClick={() => handleRemove(index)}>Delete</button>
```

Also add to the parameter list to the definition of that function:

```
const handleRemove = (index) => { /* your function */ }
```

Comment: Omg so magical. You are so right. Thank you so much.

Comment: @UsteenaMoon Happy to help!